# How to Add header in a PDF generated by interop?

Tags: c#-4.0, pdf, pdf-generation, itext

I am generating MSWord to PDF and .ppt to PDF using interop services. I want to add header  in the PDF. There are two problems I am facing:

1. I could not find the way of adding header or footer on fly while generating PDF through interop.
2. I also tried iTextSharp to add header in generated PDF, but itext sharp is creating a new PDF file which is making my process long.

Is there any way so that I can add header on fly while converting MSWord to PDF??

Note:"I am not generating MSWord to PDF using iTextSharp"

Comment: use fpdf @ www.fpdf.org

Comment: I can only use interop or iText, not any other tool.

Comment: iTextSharp cannot write to the same file that it is reading from however that doesn't mean you need to create two files. You can use iTextSharp with a `MemoryStream` instead of a `FileStream` and then save those bytes on top of the original file when you're done.